# What is the max opened files limitation on Linux?

Tags: linux, ulimit

On Linux, when a process opens a file, the OS will check the max opened files limitation.

If the limitation was 1024, what's the number mean?

Does it represent

- the number of files opened by the process
- the number of files opened by the user who owns the process
- the number of all the opened files in OS currently?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can check the Soft limits and hard limits of your system by `ulimit -a` command.

1. soft limits are simply the currently enforced limits.
2. hard limits mark the maximum value which cannot be exceeded by setting a soft limit.

Soft limits could be set by any user while hard limits are changeable only by root. Limits are a property of a **process**. They are inherited when a child process is created so system-wide limits should be set during the system initialization in init scripts and user limits should be set during user login for example by using `pam_limits`.

There are often defaults set when the machine boots. So, even though you may reset your ulimit in an individual shell, you may find that it resets back to the previous value on reboot. You may want to grep your boot scripts for the existence ulimit commands if you want to change the default.

If the limitation was 1024, means you/process can open maximum 1024 files. if you exceed this limit means `open`, `pipe` and `dup` system calls will fail:

> #### RLIMIT_NOFILE:
>
> Specifies a value one greater than the maximum file descriptor number that can be opened by  this process.  Attempts (`open(2)`, `pipe(2)`, `dup(2)`, etc.)  to exceed this limit yield the error `EMFILE`.

Comment: what does a ulimit of -1 do?

Answer (score 4):

It is a number of open file *descriptors* **per process**. They can all refer to the same file, or different files.

You can see the current limits with `ulimit -a` in the shell, or programatically with `getrlimit`. The system-wide limits are set in `/etc/security/limits.conf`.

The filesystem object model on Linux is:

```
file descriptor -> file description -> dentry -> inode
```

1. *file descriptor* is the integer number used by the application.
2. *file description* is the kernel data structure to which one or more *file descriptors* refer to.
3. *dentry* is the filename. One file can have many names (hard links).
4. *inode* is the file contents.

`dup` creates a new file descriptor to the same file description.
`open` creates a new file descriptor and a file description.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - whether it's per-process, per-user or per-system.

Answer (score -1):

If it is a linux , verify the output of:

```
ulimit -a
```

It will tell what is the limit on number of open files in the system because there is a way in linux to restrict the number of open files and also set limit on open files to unlimited that will fix the issue.